Does this decay estimate hold for $\dot{H}^1$ functions?
Is it true (is there a commonly known theorem) that says:
$f \in \dot{H}^1(\mathbb R ^n)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\displaystyle \lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ pointwise (where $\dot{H}^1$ denotes the space of functions with $|\nabla u|\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$)?
From this question here this is clearly false for $H^1$ functions when $n\geq 2$ but I was wondering whether the same would hold true in this space.
I tried the following idea:
$$|u|(r,\theta) \leq \int_r^\infty |\partial_{\tau} u|(\tau, \theta) d\tau$$
$$\leq \left(\int_r^\infty |\partial_{\tau} u|^2(\tau, \theta) \tau^{n-1}d\tau \right)^{1/2}\left(\int_r^\infty  \tau^{-n+1} d\tau \right)^{1/2} $$
$$\leq \frac{\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_r)}}{r^{\frac{n-2}{2}}}.$$
Does this estimate make sense even for non-radial functions?

Can you just shift a function up by a constant? For example, $f(x) = 1$ has zero derivative but doesn't go to zero as $|x|\to\infty$.

thanks I guess I had $u\in C^{\infty}_c$ functions in mind

A simple counter-example would be constant functions. However, even loosening the claim to $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x) = c$ for some $c$ isn't enough. For instance, $\tanh(x)$ has derivative $\mathrm{sech}^2(x)$, which is in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = -1$.
